# PayPal custom form for payment instead of default popup window

Tags: php, paypal, customization, payment-gateway, payment

I'm new to PayPal
I would like to implement a custom form to accept credit/debit card details and so users can complete the payment process (Instead of using the PayPal popup window). Is it possible?
Custom form to enter credit/debit card details will be like this,
[Custom form to recieve card details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gor1X.png)

if it is not possible, can I insert the billing address automatically from my custom form instead of asking it in the PayPal popup window...

[paypal default popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUJPS.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A regular [standard payments integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) will give the option to either Pay with PayPal in a popup, or pay with a Debit or Credit Card on your site, using the black button. You can see [a code demo here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client).  (Venmo is there for demo purposes and only shown if you `&enable-funding=venmo` on the SDK line, but in any case any extra button you don't want can be disabled)

As far as required billing information, if the transaction is set up to *not* collect shipping information ([orders create request body](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body) -> application_context -> shipping_preference -> NO_SHIPPING) , then in that case only a zip code may be required, but this can depend on the country of the payer.